# Any idea to adjust each of function contains only 2 comparison(in each pass of function)

Tags: c, binary-search

Anyone has idea to adjust the binary search code so that it uses only two comparisons instead of three (in each pass of the function)

Function 1

```
// Post: Returns 1 iff target is in arr[0..len-1], 0 otherwise.
int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
    if (len <= 0) { 
        return 0; 
    }
    int mid = len/2;
    if (target == arr[mid]) return 1;
    if (target < arr[mid]) {
        return BinarySearch(arr, mid, target);
    } else {
        return BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target); 
    }
}
```

Function 2

```
 int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
     int first = 0;
     int last = len-1;
     while (first <= last) {
         // Assert: . . .
         int mid = (first+last) / 2;
         if (target == arr[mid]) return 1;
         if (target < arr[mid]) last = mid-1;
         else first = mid+1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: may be this can help you [link] (http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-binary-search)

Comment: @LahiruAshan Thank you very much, but the code on this site still using 3 comparions for binary search function.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing it in 2 comparisions?